# Remove specific part of variable

Tags: cmake

I want to remove specific libraries from a CMake variable.

Suppose `LIB` contains the value of the variables "A;B;C",
I know use `set` to add the comtent of another variable "D" like this

```
set(LIB ${LIB};D)
```

However I tried to remove "C" from `LIB` like following

```
unset(LIB C)
```

This code does not work. 
Does anyone know good way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not how `unset` works. In your example, `unset(LIB C)` unsets both variables `LIB` and `C`. It does not remove the `C` part from `LIB`.

As all variables are internally strings in CMake, you should use `string(REPLACE)`. In your case

```
string(REPLACE C "" LIBwithoutC LIB)
```

Replaces all occurrences of `C` by an empty string and stores the result in `LIBwithoutC`. You might want to fine-tune this to remove the extra semicolon.

Comment: After trying several times, I found 

`string(REPLACE "C;" "" LIBwithoutC "${LIB}") `

works. Using "${LIB}" can treat these variable as string.
https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2016-January/062594.html

Answer (score -2):

There are at least three ways you probably already know:

```
run cmake-gui (or make edit_cache) to open the "cache editor", i.e. the GUI for cmake
the "Holzhammer" method: simply remove the complete cache or build directory and start again
and delete the entries you don't want there
open CMakeCache.txt in a text editor and edit it manually
```

There's another way to do which you maybe did not know yet.
Additionally to "-D" (define variable) cmake has also "-U" (undefine variable), which you can use to remove entries from the cache.
It goes like that: $ cmake -U*QT*.