# Change flag value in CMake if it is already set

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

A CUDA project will not build with -m32 (32 bit) option in Visual Studio later than 2013. I therefore tried adding the -m64 flag to the NVCC flags like this:

```
find_package(CUDA)
...
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -m64")
...
```

but this leads to the error

```
nvcc fatal   : redefinition of argument 'machine' // machine refers to -m
```

Sure enough on verbose build NVCC uses both -m32 and -m64 flags which leads to this error. How can I modify/remove the existing -m32 flag in the CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS variable?

Comment: `How can I modify/remove the existing -m32 flag in the CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS variable?` - If the flag is contained in `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS` variable, you may use [string(REPLACE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/string.html#id4) for remove/replace it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove specific part of variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46740873/remove-specific-part-of-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
string(REPLACE -m32 -m64 CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}")
```

[string(REPLACE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/string.html#replace)